# Justifying a text but keeping its last lines always centered

Tags: css

Is there anyway to justify a text but keeping its last (may not be separate line, the part of the text that is shown at the end of the div) always centered using pure CSS.

for example

```
                  Div Size --<Hello everyone, I would like to>---
                              show and example for the result
                                    that I want to get!
```

Using just `text-align:center` definitely doesn't solve this problem as the size of the lines (except the last line) does not get equalized. However I found something in the W3School which is `text-align-last:center`, that also does not solve the problem as it doesn't work in chrome.

Comment: fiddle for playing around: http://jsfiddle.net/assaflavie/RY5vf/

Comment: @AssafLavie: How could this example be any help, as how could the text-align: justify solve this problem ?

Comment: It's not a solution. Just a playground.

Comment: @AssafLavie: Oh, I thought you were trying to solve it out in there, sorry for the comment anyway, :p , however I got my Dreamweaver though

Answer (score 1):

So, the following hack seems to work, but it's really incredibly ugly IMO, as it relies on you controlling the line-height and using absolute positioning. Worse, it requires you to know how many lines there are in your text, which depends on the width of the div and the font-size, and probably requires JS to compute.

Anyway, after all the above disclaimers, here's the hack: Use two divs with the same text, one on top of the other. One justified, one centered. Then clip the justified one.

HTML

```
<div id="a">the last line of text in this div should be centered, while all other lines should be justified</div>
<div id="b">the last line of text in this div should be centered, while all other lines should be justified</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 1em;
    background-color: #FFEEEE;
}

#a {
    text-align: justify;
    height: 3em;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}

#b {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/assaflavie/RY5vf/4/).

Of course, the above code is hard-coded for the specific width. Again, you'll probably need JS in order to compute the number of lines in the div. I'm pretty sure that until this gets implemented in Webkit you probably won't find an elegant solution for your problem.

Comment: I took a look at the fiddle example, actually the line before the last line seems to be centered instead of being justified, I myself found a way like this, the line before the last line always seems to be the victim of the solution, it gets messed up.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of your screen being a different width. I'v updated the fiddle to use a fixed width for the div. it works for me.

Comment: I use IE and the line before the last is not exactly justified, I say this because the o is pretty further than the side from the first letter in the upper line which is C, so it feels like it is centered.

Comment: Well, that's just part of the hackary of this solution - in IE I get a different number of lines, and so the height of #a has to be adjusted. If you implement this "properly" with JS it'll work.

Comment: Yeah I can do it in JS but just out of curiosity I wanted to know if there is a specific solution for this in css, but according to this discussion and your answer, I think that is not "simply" possible to do so just in css.

Comment: Thank you very much Assaf, I gave you the +1 for your priceless help but I will try to find an efficient CSS solution and if I can find it I post as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The [`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last) property was designed for purposes like this. Originally a Microsoft invention, it has now been described in CSS Text Module Level 3 WD and implemented in Firefox, too; however, Firefox still needs the `-moz-` prefix. So you would use, in addition to `text-align: justify`, the following declarations:

```
text-align-last: center;
-moz-text-align-last: center;
```

Beyond this, there is little hope. Support is to be expected in the next version of Chrome. This is hardly a crucial matter where you should try some contrived techniques to implement this simple feature—you would need to intercept block formatting in a browser at a fairly low level.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, my answer strictly, and with proper references, answers the question “Is there anyway to justify a text but keeping its last [line] [...] always centered using pure CSS.” The question mentions “W3School”, which can give no serious answers.

Answer (score -1):

This will achieve the desired effect:

```
<div>the last line of text in this div should be centered, while all other lines <p style="text-align:center; margin: 0;">should be justified</p></div>
```

Comment: Work only if you know where to break the line.

Comment: The last line before the one which needs to be centered doesn't get justified beside what Loqbal mentioned. this a terrible way to do this.